# Why are Bangalore and Gibraltar named Bangalore and Gibraltar?

Tags: apex-legends

Most of the Apex Legends cast have fairly straightforward codenames: Bloodhound's a tracker, Lifeline heals, Mirage does holograms, Octane uses fuel (well, drugs) to go fast, Wraith becomes ghostly, Pathfinder scouts, Caustic has his poisons...

And then there's Bangalore and Gibraltar. Google tells me Bangalore is [the former name of the city of Bengaluru in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore), and Gibraltar is [an independent territory located on the Iberian peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar). Neither of those seem to match the pattern set by the rest of the cast's names, and they also don't seem to be referenced or explained anywhere in their lore or in-game dialogue that I can find.

I assume there's some cultural reference I'm missing here, but searching "[character] name meaning" just gets me how-to-play guides. Can someone help me understand the relevance of these names?

Comment: There's also [Mozambique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozambique).

Comment: "*an independent territory located on the Iberian peninsula*" - ha, no. It's Britain's little piece of strategic territory in the western Mediterranean.

Comment: @Randal'Thor My apologies, didn't mean to be inaccurate. My understanding of Gibraltar's political situation is definitely not as good as it should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only explanations I've found speculate that Bangalore's name is a reference to the [Bangalore torpedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_torpedo), a type of explosive device used for breaching wire obstacles and clearing mines. Since the character has several abilities related to explosives this seems like the most likely explanation.

Gibraltar's name is a reference to the [Rock of Gibraltar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_of_Gibraltar), a famous promontory which was the site of a prominent fortification. Calling something "as solid as the rock of Gibraltar" is a well-known phrase used to indicate that something is very safe, well-defended or dependable.

Comment: Accepting this one specifically because of the information that the Rock of Gibraltar has/had a famous fortification, which given his 'walking shield' playstyle makes a lot of sense as a name for him. Both of these are good answers, though, thank you both.

Answer (score 5):

Their names seem to be appropriate for their personalities and power-sets;

A [**Bangalore**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_torpedo) (torpedo) is an explosive device used for breaking through obstacles.

> Call in an artillery strike that slowly creeps across the landscape.
>
> <sub><sup>[Apex Legends - official EA Site: Bangalore](https://www.ea.com/games/apex-legends/about/characters/bangalore)</sup></sub>

**[Gibraltar](https://www.ea.com/games/apex-legends/about/characters/makoa-gibraltar)** is a [gigantic immobile rock.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_of_Gibraltar)

> He’s now become an icon in the Apex Games, **putting himself in the line of fire to protect his squad** and send his opponents running for cover.
>
> <sub><sup>[Apex Legends - official EA Site: Gibraltar](https://www.ea.com/games/apex-legends/about/characters/makoa-gibraltar)</sup></sub>